# Screen flickering issue in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, hp

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, my screen keeps on flickering and I can see frame drops. Restarting my PC doesn't solve the problem. I have a HP Pavilion ab032tx, dual booted with Windows 10.The problem does not appear in when using Windows. Thanks in advance!

Some specs about my pc

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"

Linux pirateking-HP-Pavilion-Notebook 4.13.0-43-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:18:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 5500 [103c:8096]
Kernel driver in use: i915

DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=10586682c361fef67a15272413197 0580800000027710008
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue after kernel update to 4.13.0-43, my laptop is Acer 573g. On Windows (also dual boot) screen totally fine.

I temporarily resolved this problem by booting with previous kernel (4.13.0-41 in my case), and now wait for another kernel update..